# Android how to turn off gps icon after press return back button to home screen ?

Tags: android, gps

I have this problem, I using GPS from my app to get latitude and longitude,when I want to return to home Icon GPS always show from top of my Mobile device,how I can turn off it after return to home screen

[image]
my code.

```
public class doctorlocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
    String lat;
    String provider;
    protected double latitude,longitude; 
    protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.doctorlocation);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);   
    }

        @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     //txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    //txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    String str = "Latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+" \nLongitude: "+location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    latitude=location.getLatitude();

    longitude=location.getLongitude();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
     Log.d("Latitude","disable");

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps turned off ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
     Log.d("Latitude","enable");

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps turned on ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }

      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code on `onPause()` of that `Activity`.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    Log.i("onPause", "inside onPause");
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);//locationManager.removeUpdates(this) ;
    locationManager = null;
    }
```

Comment: thank u I have add your code when press resume button to home I have error unfortunately your app has stopped.

Comment: `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);` use this on `onResume`.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling and Disabling the GPS is in the hands of the user. You can show him a Dialog to inform him about disabling the GPS. Keep two buttons on the dialog in that case - one for "Settings" and another one for "ok" or "cancel".

```
public static void promptForGPS(
        final Activity activity)
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        final String action = Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;
        final String message = "Disable GPS....Message here"
            + " Click OK to go to"
            + " location services settings to let you do so.";

        builder.setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                        activity.startActivity(new Intent(action));
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                        d.cancel();
                    }
            });
        builder.create().show();
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but now I have one error (ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS cannot be resolved or is not a field)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS

Answer (score 0):

The best I have found is

```
onResume()
{
     // Request for GPS Location
     //location.requestLocationUpdates()
}
```

and

```
onPause()
{
     // Remove location
     // location.removeUpdates()
}
```

By calls removeUpdates() method it will stop GPS whenever your Activity is not in forground. This way you can stop GPS as well as it will stop draining your battery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the LocationManager that you no longer need location updates when your App enters into background, by using

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

in your onPause() method.

You should also move your call to

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

to onResume(); so that location updates will resume once you re-enter your App.